# Getting undefined when attempting to get user input

Tags: javascript

In the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/QWNqdXE) I am trying to get text from input field. I am then trying to creat an object from that data. I get undefined for the userData even though I am returning it in my event listener.

```
class Name {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const getUserData = (function() {
  
    let userInput = document.getElementById('name').value;

    return { name: userInput};

})();

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userData = getUserData();
});

console.log(userData);
const nameObj = new Name(userData);
console.log(nameObj);
```

Comment: Why don't you read your errors in console? *"Uncaught ReferenceError: userData is not defined"* You cannot access variables outside the scope. JS is asyncronous. `console.log()` will not wait for user input like i.e: in C :)

Comment: That is the issue. How can I save the data for use outside the event listener callback function. I want to be able to create an object to use later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Name {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const getUserData = function() {
  
    let userInput = document.getElementById('name').value;

    return { name: userInput};

};

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userData = getUserData();
  
  console.log(userData);
const nameObj = new Name(userData);
console.log(nameObj);
});
```

```css
#btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.form-container {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <form id="test-form">
   <div class="form-container">
     <input id="name" type="name" name="name" placeholder="type your name here">
     <div id="btn">Click Me</div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: but how can you later use the new object outside of the event listener callback function?